# Building an equation

Tags: performance, julia, symbolic-math

I've developed a function in the Julia language, using the `SymEngine` library, which builds an equation. This function works quite quickly, returning a lambdified equation.

The problem is, calculation of the value of this equation in the point takes too long time! And as the equation becomes longer, the calculation time also increases.

Is there a way to optimize the equation, generated by the function?

```
function func()

  @vars x y z myu

  longitude=atan(y/x)+pi*sign(y)*(1-sign(x))/2
  r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^(1/2)

  dUx=0
  dUy=0
  dUz=0
  for i=2:degree
      for j=0:degree

          index=1+j; for ll=2:i-1 index+=ll+1; end

          P_i=(myu^2-1)^i
          for k=1:i+j P_i=diff(P_i,myu) end

          if(i>20) F=factorial(Int128(i)); else F=factorial(i); end
          P_ij=(((1-myu^2)^(j/2))/(F*2^i))*P_i

          if(P_ij!=0)
            CS_exp=CS[index,3]*cos(j*longitude)+CS[index,4]*sin(j*longitude)
            CS_diff_x= j*CS[index,4]*cos(j*longitude)*(-y/(x^2+y^2)) - j*CS[index,3]*sin(j*longitude)*(-y/(x^2+y^2))
            CS_diff_y= j*CS[index,4]*cos(j*longitude)*( x/(x^2+y^2)) - j*CS[index,3]*sin(j*longitude)*( x/(x^2+y^2))
            CS_diff_z= 0

            L=P_ij(z/r)

            dUx+= GMe*(diff((L*(Req/r)^i)/r,x)*CS_exp + CS_diff_x*(L*(Req/r)^i)/r)
            dUy+= GMe*(diff((L*(Req/r)^i)/r,y)*CS_exp + CS_diff_y*(L*(Req/r)^i)/r)
            dUz+= GMe*(diff((L*(Req/r)^i)/r,z)*CS_exp + CS_diff_z*(L*(Req/r)^i)/r)

          end
       end
  end

  return lambdify(dUx, [x,y,z], cse=true),lambdify(dUy, [x,y,z], cse=true),lambdify(dUz, [x,y,z], cse=true)

end

dU=func();

dy= [
       dU[1](y[1],y[2],y[3]),
       dU[2](y[1],y[2],y[3]),
       dU[3](y[1],y[2],y[3])
    ]
```

The calculation of `dy` takes too long. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to tell us what you are actually calculating there. Just saying _this function is too slow_ is not enough and off-topic for the lack of context.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead. Actually, I'd recommend that. Link back to this question, but stop editing this one. Make sure you've read the [help/on-topic] before posting your new question so it fits the guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

I've also commented on the julia slack, but just if anyone else is reading, as I see you've not updated the question according to my comments.

You can see Julia's general performance tips [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html). I suggest you read this. You are falling into at least two of the performance gotchas:

1. You are initializing `dUx`, `dUy` and `dUz` as `Int`s first, but change their type to `Float64`s in the first assignment. That trips the compiler. The solution is to initialize them to `0.`
2. You are using `degree` and `CS` that appear to be captured global variables, which makes it impossible for the compiler to specialize. The solution is to pass them as arguments to the function.

Not that the second issue also means that your code is not runnable, because we don't have access to `degree` and `CS`. If your code is not runnable it's very hard to comment on.

Here's what you can do yourself to fix this:

1. Use the Traceur.jl package to check your code, using `@trace func()`. That will check your code for the common performance gotchas.
2. Use the BenchmarkTools package (with `@btime`) to evaluate any improvements.
3. Once you've done that, use the `Profile` module (or even better, [Juno's inbuilt profiler](https://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/juno_frontend.html#Juno.@profiler) to see which lines in your code are slow.

Once you've done that, if you still have problems, please comment here with the results from the profiler, and update your code to be runnable, and we'll be happy to take a look again.

Comment: The @trace gives strange results- I can't understand the output

Comment: The point is, the function `func()` works fine. But the calculation of the value in the point works slow...

Comment: Can you not update the post with your edited code?